# Copy a column with a formula to another tab

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a column in one tab that is a concatenate of two other columns that needs to be moved to a new tab.  As you might expect, the formulas are copied rather than the values.

I saw [this from @Serge] [Copy every row of Data from one sheet that has a given value in column K to another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127923/copy-every-row-of-data-from-one-sheet-that-has-a-given-value-in-column-k-to-anot) which is where I think I need to go, but wanted to see what I was missing (because I usually do :)  )

```
var sourceTab = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var xportTab = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
sourceTab.getRange("P1:P").copyTo(xportTab.getRange("A1"));  // new description
```

Any other tricks someone can suggest?

- Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to copy just the values, right?

You can do it like this:

```js
function copyExample() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = source.getRange(1,16,source.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange(1,1,values.length,1).setValues(values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function copyExample() {

  var idSheet = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx";//listes des propositions (ttes valeurs)
  var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idSheet);  

  var idSheet3 = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"; //Liste des propositions sans contact
  var mySheet3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idSheet3);  


  var values = mySheet.getRange(1,2,mySheet.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  mySheet3.getRange(1,2,values.length,2).setValues(values);


}
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be nice!