# Re: Copy every row of Data from one sheet that has a given value to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I saw your answer in an old thread and i wanted to ask for clarification. This is the thread i am referring to: [Copy every row of Data from one sheet that has a given value in column K to another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127923/copy-every-row-of-data-from-one-sheet-that-has-a-given-value-in-column-k-to-anot)

My issue is, I'm using a version of your skeleton script, but i am having some trouble. Instead of the script copying the entire row, it seems to be copying the first column in the conditional rows and pasting the results of the array all in a single row.

Here is my script as is:

```
  function formSubmitCriticalAltThree(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var target = ss.getSheetByName("Chad");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var line = new Array();
 var targetArray= new Array();
  for (n=0;n<data.length;++n){ // iterate rows
   if (data[n][10] == "cbellani"){ // if condition is true copy the whole row to target
     line.push(data[n]);// copy the whole row
   }//if
  }//for
   if(line.length>0){// if there is something to copy
     targetArray.push(line)}// add row to destination
target.getRange(3,1,targetArray.length,targetArray[0].length).setValues(targetArray);
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but I think it should look like this:

```
function formSubmitCriticalAltThree(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
   var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
   var target = ss.getSheetByName("Chad");
   var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
   var targetArray = new Array();
   for (var n = 0; n < data.length; ++n){ // iterate rows
      if (data[n][10] == "cbellani") { // if condition is true copy the whole row to target
         targetArray.push(data[n])}// add row to destination
      }//if
   }//for
   target.getRange(3,1,targetArray.length,targetArray[0].length).setValues(targetArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. When I run the function you have posted it returns a single row of only the first column of every qualifying row. Essentially its one row of timestamped times. Do i need to also iterate columns?