# I want to copy Row to Data Sheet if D on Raw Contain Yes Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 Sheets Data, Raw. I want to copy all data of the row if `"Column D"` of Raw contain `Yes`. Do not want blank boxes.

[image]

Comment: Ok, and? What did you try?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127923/copy-every-row-of-data-from-one-sheet-that-has-a-given-value-in-column-k-to-anot) is a solution that does almost exactly what you want.  Just a google search and a couple of modifications needed.